# Dual monitors "reset" intermittently when certain programmes are run

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have updated to the latest driver, which has made the problem less frequent, but still a daily or more occurrence.

Windows 7 SP1 64-bit
NVIDIA NVS 300, NVIDIA driver 8.17.12.6570
Primary monitor: Samsung SyncMaster 2333 Generic PnP monitor, Microsoft driver 6.1.7600.16385
Secondary monitor: DELL E2209W(Digital) with Dell driver 1.0.0.0

Comment: What programs cause this issue?

Comment: Oops missed that bit. Cisco VPN causes the most frequent issues. It has occurred with MS Word too though.

Comment: I should add that others in my workplace have the same PC and have similar issues, also seeing problems with MS Outlook.

Comment: MS outlook IS a problem ;) What kind of graphics card is the NVIDIA NVS 300, never heard of it, I thought I know them all?

Comment: It is upon connection to the VPN that the windows reset. By reset I mean the primary desktop flicks between monitors and ends up with all windows in the primary desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you first hit up the Event Viewer and what exactly crashes the system.  The OS usually logs what happens under the system log.  That is where I would start first. Next I'd go under Control Panel/Performance Tools/Advanced tools.  Windows automatically flags misbehaving device drivers.  If not, click the "Generate System Health Report" tool.  That will force Windows to check your device drivers.

Lets at least exhaust our tools before we start speculating. . .

Comment: Diagnostic Results present one warning: Symptom: Missing Events in Event Log 
Details: Investigate why 19% (7,709) events were lost during data collection. The settings for Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) maximum buffers and buffer size may not be optimal depending on which data sets are being collected.

Comment: I need to replicate the behaviour to get the exact time to get the event logs. There are events regarding The Software Protection service, if that sheds any light. May not be related.